# Unable to create a breakpoint on a line in a ashx file that uses Linq extensions like OrderBy or Where

Tags: c#, linq, debugging

I've some strange issues with a asp.net 4.5 project about trying to debug a ashx handler.

The code compiles successfully on the line that uses Linq extension OrderBy , but i could not create a breakpoint ( This is not a valid location for breakpoint ) exactly on that line. vs2019 automatically puts a breakpoint before that line.

And if i try to debug the ashx file , i can step over this line but nothing is executed .

I have no problem about debugging the project , VS2019 simply just ignores that line .

Thanks,

```
 List<string> list = new List<string>();

 foreach(DataRow row in dtTable.Rows)
 {
       list.Add(row["DIM2"].ToString());
 }

 list.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: Please send your code.

Comment: I edited the post and attached the code

Comment: Could not put a breakpoint to the last line for debugging

Comment: `OrderBy` returns a new ordered list so using it like this doesn't actually do anything.